# Deep Learning Log Loss Function Analysis

Tags: partial-derivative, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Given the set of parameters of a logistic regression model, and a small set of data points, calculate the j^{th} partial derivative of the log-loss function for some j.

What kind of data points could be given here?
The formula for the log-loss function I have is l(w,b)= 1/m ∑_(i=1)->m [ln⁡(1+e^(-y_i(w∙x+b)))]

I get that I want to differentiate with respect to the weight w, but I'm just not sure what this type of problem could look like.  Some advice would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format the math thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $(x_i, y_i), i=1, \ldots, m$ where $y_i$'s are either $1$ or $-1$.. These are the data points.

You are trying to build a linear prediction function and determining $w$ and $b$ which minimizes the loss is your desired task.

Comment: So if I have two points (-1,1) and (3,7), I can build a function that divides the space into two.  How would I use the formula to calculate partial derivatives?

Comment: Your $y$ should only be $1$ or $-1$, when you perform partial derivative for $w_j$'s, you treat the other variables as constant. Note that the solution need not have a closed form in general, but you should still try to write down the equation.